# CSS3 HTML5 and JQuery Matrix

Tags: jquery, html, css, d3.js, flot

I need to achieve something like . 
[image]
Each brown circle represents an image.
It will be a plus to have mouse-over capabilities or popover.

The idea is to place different images on a matrix with 4 responsive quadrants (currently supporting Bootstrap). I tried to do it using D3 and Flot but didn't find any sample to start with.

Comment: I don't think it's too clear what you're trying to do. You're making a 2x2 matrix of images, how is that responsive (or how do you want it to be)? What have you tried before and what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution with flot: http://jsfiddle.net/w4z7vxzh/

The data for the circles looks like this:

```
var graphData = [{
    data: [
        // format: [x, y, size], x and y between 0 and 20
        [3, 18, 1],
        [8, 18, 1.1],
        [6, 15, 0.9],
        ...
```

I had to inline flot and change the point drawing method to allow dynamic sized points/circles (marked with `// CHANGES HERE` in the flot code):

```
var scale = axisx.p2c(1) - axisx.p2c(0);
ctx.arc(x, y, series.data[Math.floor(i / ps)][2] * scale, 0, shadow ? Math.PI : Math.PI * 2, false);
```

Tooltips on mouse-over are also implemented.
And the graph resizes when the window resizes (without bootstrap for now).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve this without images, if you wish.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="chart">
        <div class="quadrant1"></div>
        <div class="quadrant2"></div>
        <div class="quadrant3"></div>
        <div class="quadrant4"></div>
        <div class="item1" title="Hover me 1"></div>
        <div class="item2" title="Hover me 2"></div>
        <div class="item3" title="Hover me 3"></div>
        <div class="item4" title="Hover me 4"></div>
        <div class="item5" title="Hover me 5"></div>
        <div class="item6" title="Hover me 6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    max-width:80%;
    margin:auto;}

.chart {
    height:0px; /* can't set 100% height, since this would be calculated as a % of the parent element */
    padding-bottom:100%; /*make height relative to the width */
    width:100%; /* Fill the wrapper (makes the chart responsive) */
    position:relative; /* MAke sure the items are positioned relative to the chart, not the body, etc. */}

.quadrant1,
.quadrant2,
.quadrant3, 
.quadrant4 {
    height:0px;
    padding-bottom:calc(49.5% - 4px); /* (Desired height - border size * 2) */
    width:calc(49.5% - 4px); /* (Desired width - border size * 2) */
    float:left;
    border:2px solid black;}

/** Create the Grid Spacing Between the Quadrants **/
.quadrant1 {
    margin-right:1%;
    margin-bottom:1%;}
.quadrant2 {margin-bottom:1%;}
.quadrant3 {margin-right:1%;}
.quadrant4 {}


.item1 {
    position:absolute; /* remove from the document flow, position according to nearest ancestor with position */
    border:2px solid brown; /* Hopefully this one is self-explanitory :-) */
    height:calc(8% - 4px); /* (Desired height - border size * 2) */
    width:calc(8% - 4px); /* (Desired width - border size * 2) */
    border-radius:500px; /* some number that will never be exceeded by the size of the circle */
    top:50%; /* Vertical position - could also use 'bottom' */
    left:50%; /* Horizontal position - could also use 'bottom' */
    margin-top:-4%; /* offset half the height of the circle to center it on the coordinates */
    margin-left:-4%;} /* offset half the width of the circle to center it on the coordinates */

.item2 {position:absolute;border:2px solid brown;height:calc(8% - 4px);width:calc(8% - 4px);border-radius:500px;top:25%;left:25%;margin-top:-4%;margin-left:-4%;}
.item3 {position:absolute;border:2px solid brown;height:calc(8% - 4px);width:calc(8% - 4px);border-radius:500px;top:75%;left:75%;margin-top:-4%;margin-left:-4%;}
.item4 {position:absolute;border:2px solid brown;height:calc(8% - 4px);width:calc(8% - 4px);border-radius:500px;top:30%;left:80%;margin-top:-4%;margin-left:-4%;}
.item5 {position:absolute;border:2px solid brown;height:calc(4% - 4px);width:calc(4% - 4px);border-radius:500px;top:5%;left:95%;margin-top:-2%;margin-left:-2%;}
.item6 {position:absolute;border:2px solid brown;height:calc(15% - 4px);width:calc(15% - 4px);border-radius:500px;top:90%;left:10%;margin-top:-7.5%;margin-left:-7.5%;}

.item1:hover, 
.item2:hover,
.item3:hover,
.item4:hover,
.item5:hover, 
.item6:hover {background:#0066CC;border-color:#333333;}
```

Simply add and position as many items as needed.  If you want to still use images for some reason, you could also use the `background-image` property to insert them via CSS.  Tested in Chrome/Safari, but should be pretty compatible across the spectrum (no IE8 or less - rounded corners aren't supported.)

You could also plug in Bootstrap's tooltip or popover if desired.

CodePen here: http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/eNgGWp